# Dynamic storyboard redirect on XCode 8 with SWIFT 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Using SWIFT 3 on XCode 8, is there a way to redirect the app to your Custom Storyboard **without** renaming the field "Main storyboard file base name" on info.plist file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect your app to your custom storyboard via the AppDelegate, so you don't have to care about the "Main storyboard file base name" on info.plist file.

You need to get the instance of the initial View Controller of your custom storyboard and then call:

```
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window! else { return }
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
window.rootViewController = yourCustomViewControllerInstance
```

This can be called inside `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)`

Hope it helps.